# Controller in helper_method not showing views Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this view `new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>EVALUATING MODEL PERFORMANCE</h1>
<%= test %>
<%= "#{controller_name}/#{action_name}" %>
```

The controller is `articles_controller.rb`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    y = R.pull "capture.output(summary(rnorm(10)))"
    puts y
    end

    helper_method :test
    def test
    sample_size = 10
    R.eval "x <- rnorm(#{sample_size})"
    R.eval "summary(x)"
    R.eval "sd(x)"
    y = R.pull "capture.output(summary(rnorm(10)))"
    puts y
    end
end
```

Why does the output (shown here: [ruby in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WteNQ.png)) does not include the results of the `test` method?

Answer (score 0):

you need to `return y` at the end of your `test` method. 
`puts` doesnt actually return anything (it returns `nil`), it just prints to the console. so if `puts` is the last thing in your method, it will be returned. but since it doesnt return anything, there is nothing for your view to display.

by returning `y`, your view will be able to display the string (though i expect the formatting to be all over the place).

Comment: so... i got the output... but as you say... the output isnot good.... how to make it more like table ? or atleast just ascci is okay...., thank you...

Comment: well youre printing it to an html page, you'd need to parse it and write it with html and erb. you can try putting a `pre` tag around it

Comment: `pre` tag doesn't show like in the console... i just want to have format just like console to be added to web... and i still don't understand